# Maven build error on @Nonnull annotation in type parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using the com.google.code.findbugs jsr305 annotations for null analysis in eclipse and my project seems to compile and run just fine within eclipse.
However when I try to build it with maven I'm getting this error: `annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration`

Here's an example:

src/test/Main.java

```java
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");
        method(list);
    }
    
    private static void method(List<@Nonnull String> list) {//< error here
        for (String str : list) {
            print(str);
        }
    }
    
    private static void print(@Nonnull String str) { 
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>test.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <outputDirectory>JAR</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

eclipse settings for null analysis

.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.inheritNullAnnotations=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.missingNonNullByDefaultAnnotation=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nonnull=javax.annotation.Nonnull
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nonnull.secondary=
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nonnullbydefault=javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nonnullbydefault.secondary=
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nullable=javax.annotation.CheckForNull
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nullable.secondary=
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.annotation.nullanalysis=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.methodParameters=do not generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.8
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.APILeak=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.annotatedTypeArgumentToUnannotated=info
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.annotationSuperInterface=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.autoboxing=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.comparingIdentical=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.deadCode=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.deprecation=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.deprecationInDeprecatedCode=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.deprecationWhenOverridingDeprecatedMethod=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.discouragedReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.emptyStatement=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.explicitlyClosedAutoCloseable=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.fallthroughCase=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.fatalOptionalError=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.fieldHiding=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.finalParameterBound=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.finallyBlockNotCompletingNormally=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.hiddenCatchBlock=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.includeNullInfoFromAsserts=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.incompatibleNonInheritedInterfaceMethod=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.incompleteEnumSwitch=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.indirectStaticAccess=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.localVariableHiding=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.methodWithConstructorName=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingDefaultCase=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingDeprecatedAnnotation=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingEnumCaseDespiteDefault=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingHashCodeMethod=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingOverrideAnnotation=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingOverrideAnnotationForInterfaceMethodImplementation=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingSerialVersion=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.missingSynchronizedOnInheritedMethod=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.noEffectAssignment=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.noImplicitStringConversion=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.nonExternalizedStringLiteral=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.nonnullParameterAnnotationDropped=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.nonnullTypeVariableFromLegacyInvocation=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.nullAnnotationInferenceConflict=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.nullReference=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.nullSpecViolation=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.nullUncheckedConversion=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.overridingPackageDefaultMethod=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.parameterAssignment=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.pessimisticNullAnalysisForFreeTypeVariables=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.possibleAccidentalBooleanAssignment=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.potentialNullReference=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.potentiallyUnclosedCloseable=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.rawTypeReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.redundantNullAnnotation=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.redundantNullCheck=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.redundantSpecificationOfTypeArguments=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.redundantSuperinterface=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportMethodCanBePotentiallyStatic=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportMethodCanBeStatic=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.reportPreviewFeatures=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.specialParameterHidingField=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.staticAccessReceiver=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.suppressOptionalErrors=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.suppressWarnings=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.suppressWarningsNotFullyAnalysed=info
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.syntacticNullAnalysisForFields=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.syntheticAccessEmulation=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.terminalDeprecation=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.typeParameterHiding=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unavoidableGenericTypeProblems=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.uncheckedTypeOperation=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unclosedCloseable=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.undocumentedEmptyBlock=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unhandledWarningToken=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unlikelyCollectionMethodArgumentType=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unlikelyCollectionMethodArgumentTypeStrict=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unlikelyEqualsArgumentType=info
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unnecessaryElse=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unnecessaryTypeCheck=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unqualifiedFieldAccess=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unstableAutoModuleName=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedDeclaredThrownException=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedDeclaredThrownExceptionExemptExceptionAndThrowable=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedDeclaredThrownExceptionIncludeDocCommentReference=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedDeclaredThrownExceptionWhenOverriding=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedExceptionParameter=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedImport=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedLabel=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedLocal=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedObjectAllocation=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedParameter=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedParameterIncludeDocCommentReference=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedParameterWhenImplementingAbstract=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedParameterWhenOverridingConcrete=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedPrivateMember=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedTypeParameter=ignore
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.unusedWarningToken=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.varargsArgumentNeedCast=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.release=disabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.8
```

Trying to avoid having to suppress null warnings for uses of prevElem, the code around this already ensures the List elements are not null.

So eclipse seems to recognise and compile the `List<@Nonnull T> x` just fine but maven isn't having it. This is compiling to target 1.8 but I've tried building with 16 and that just gives me a slightly more verbose error `annotation @javax.annotation.Nonnull not applicable in this type context`

Is this something that just isn't allowed, if so how/why does eclipse manage to compile it?

Is there a better solution than just suppressing the null warning or redundantly checking for null in the for loop?

Comment: Please show a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): a Java class and the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: @howlger added a full example showing the problem.